# Why doesn't a def statement work in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I'm new to Python. But, I can't get a def statement to work. Running Python 3.7, Spyder 4. When I execute this, Spyder skips right past the def statement as though it doesn't exist. Even if I just have the def statement without the comments. What am I doing wrong? (Sigh... do not rule out stupid user error.)

```
"""
Created on Wed Mar  3 13:59:36 2021

@author: larryj
"""

# This is a test.

def add(x,y):
    ###
    This is a simple way to add numbers
    ###
    x = x + y
    
add(2,3)
print(x)
```

Comment: Your `This is a simple way to add numbers` isn't a comment; it's a syntax error. Having three hashes on surrounding lines does not make something a comment.

Comment: As @khelwood pointed out, use `"""` (triple-quotes) instead of triple-hash `###` so that `This is a simple way to add numbers` becomes a comment. Or simple do `# This is a simple way to add numbers` with a hash in front and you can remove the triple-hashes completely.

Comment: Thanks. I made three mistakes - an incorrect form for the comment, not adding a return with the variable being returned and not setting the add() function as an equations.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a return statement at the very end of the function. If you want to get the value back from the function it needs to return it (see edit below). If you just want to print the result (not sure why you want that) then you can add the print statement in the function itself.

```
# This is a test.

def add(x,y):
    x = x + y
    return x

x = add(2,3)
print(x)
```

Comment: And `###` does not work for a multi-line comment.